# Blanking out segments in a Vega sunburst diagram

Tags: tree, vega, sunburst-diagram

I'm using Vega to create a sunburst diagram where each segment of the innermost circle represents a unique resource, and then the circles around it represent one of those original resources, a new resource, or are unknown.

I'm using a colour scale to fill in the colours of the segments based on the resource name like so (taken from https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/sunburst/):

```
"fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "name"}
```

which works fine. However, in the cases where the resource is unknown (this is a boolean set by a 'hide' variable in the data), I'd like the segment to be invisible (i.e. white on white background). I've tried implementing this as a conditional:

```
"fill":  [
              { "test": "datum.hide != 0", "value": {"scale": "color", "field": "name"}}, 
              {"value": "white"}
          ],
```

but this doesn't work. It seem like the conditional only works if both values are fixed colour names, like so:

```
"fill":  [
              { "test": "datum.hide != 0", "value": "red"}, 
              {"value": "white"}
          ],
```

which generates

[Sunburst showing relationships between segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr2TX.png)

which is exactly what I want but with each visible segment the colour from the scale. Is there any way to have both a test condition and be able to use a scale for filling in the colours?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer going through the tests case in the vega repo:

```
  "fill":  [
      { "test": "datum.hide != 1", "scale": "color", "field": "name"},
      {"value": "white"}
  ],
```